# opening a website via its server ip

Tags: networking, google-chrome-extensions

I don't want to use a website via its domain address, so I came with the idea to use its IP address to reach the website.  The problem is when I open the server IP address, it just says "It works!"

Am I correct that I should use a host header for http to tell the server to bring that website for me?  If I should modify the headers, I assume I should use some Google Chrome extensions.  If that's the case, what extensions should I use?

The website is `convert2mp3.net` and the IP address is `87.98.246.174`.

Comment: Before you start seeking extensions for your browser to do what the browser will do anyway, perhaps you should clarify _why_ you need to do this.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I need this because the ISP has censored the website(for no reason!) and I didn't want to use VPN. does it make any sense at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably wasting your time. The browser sends its request to the IP address it gets by resolving the server name using DNS. It adds the actual server name as a `Host:` header automatically and the web server uses the `Host:` header to determine which pages it should serve.

If you give the browser the IP address of the server and substitute the server name in the `Host:` header by some other means then you've arrived at the same contents as the browser would send.

It's unlikely your ISP will block your site 'for no reason'. Maybe they're actually blocking access to some other site on the same server and you've been caught up in the fallout. Your best solution is to contact your ISP and ask them what's going on.

Failing that, use a VPN

Answer (score -1):

You've got to consider what the ISP's equipment may look at to block access to a website. If access isn't being blocked by IP address, their equipment would see the domain name in the address the browser provides with the [host header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Field_values). So, if you manually emulate what your browser will do automatically, you'll likely get the same results.

A simple way to test that hypothesis is to use a telnet program, e.g., PuTTY, if you have a Microsoft Windows system, which no longer provides a telnet client by default, or, if you are using an OS X or Linux system, use the telnet command from a shell prompt. With PuTTY, select the "raw" option for "connection type" and put 80 in the port field. Put the name of the website, e.g., convert2mp3.net, if that's the site for which you wish to test, in the Host Name (or IP Address) field. Click on **Logging** and set the logging option to "Printable Output" and specify a location for the log file. Click on **Connection** and set the TCP keepalive value to a few seconds, e.g., 5. Click on **Session** again to get back to the first screen and click on the **Save** button to save the session with a name so you can use it again, if you have a need to do so. Then click on the **Open** button to establish the connection to the server. Type `GET / HTTP/1.1` and hit Enter. Then type `Host: convert2mp3.net` and hit Enter a couple of times. You should see output from the website and what you typed and the website's response will be saved in the PuTTY log file at the location you specified. If you test initially with example.com as the website, you can get an idea of what is a normal response from a website, since example.com is used specifically for illustrative purposes. I've also put figures and a log file at [Testing access to a website using PuTTY](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/server/putty-test.php), if you want to see further details.

If access to a website is blocked by an ISP, there are many VPN and proxy server services available.